# Variable type changes after retrieving from Eloquent model in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have table named marital_status in Database. This contains only two columns user_id (of type Integer) and the another column named is_married (of type boolean).

Therefore, when I retrieve marital status of user via eloquent model, i would except boolean.

```
   Auth::user()->maritalStatus // equals always string not boolean.
```

Results are correct, but instead of boolean I am getting string '0' or '1'. Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can address this in the model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'is_married' => 'boolean'
];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Comment: Awesome! this is exactly i was looking for! Thanks.